# How to print bitmap image on the full size of the paper

Tags: c#, printing, margin

I am currently creating a bitmap of 1632x1056 (17x11 at 96 dpi) pixels. I want to print this image on an 11in x 17in paper.

I can open this file up in Windows Photo Viewer and print it perfectly, but when I use the print function in c#, there is always a small margin that appears so it shifts my image to not fit on the whole page.
This is my code settings for the print document

```
    Image glControlBits;
    private void PrintImage()
    {
        //print the document
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("PDI", 1100, 1700);
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        pd.OriginAtMargins = true;
        //pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea = new RectangleF(0, 0, viewSize.X, viewSize.Y);
        //pd.DefaultPageSettings.HardMarginX = 0;
        //pd.DefaultPageSettings.HardMarginY = 0;
        //pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution
        PrintDialog pdialog = new PrintDialog();
        pdialog.Document = pd;
        if (pdialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //set the print image to be the bitmap of the glcontrol
            glControlBits = GrabScreenshot();
            //save the bitmap, for debugging purposes
            glControlBits.Save(@"C:\Users\Shane\Desktop\testbitmap.bmp");
            pd.Print();
        }
        else return;
    }
```

I think the problem might be that the hardmargin values are set by the printer, and the values are 25 for hardmarginx and 16 for hardmarginy. Is there a way to set these to zero so that is the no margin offset when I print? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are not using the PageBorderless property.  Try using the property as indicated in [the MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.pageborderless(v=vs.110).aspx)

Let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: According to the documentation, a lot of printers do not support this property. Also I'm not sure how to implement this feature

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason why printers set a hard margin.  For some printers, they really mean it.

For laser printers in particular, there's usually a signal for page top detect from the engine and the controller for the printer will get that and carefully time when to start lighting up the video circuitry (seriously - it's called video circuitry because it works the same as a CRT display) and write a charge onto the paper. Start too soon and you are hitting the internals for the first scanline.  Scanlines are written by scanning the beam over the page and feeding the output of a FIFO into the beam control circuitry. There is only so much area that the beam can cover on the paper and it has a hard limit. You can't change it.

Ink jet printers can do pretty well L/R on a page but there are often mechanical reasons why they can't manage T/B as the paper may (for example) not be held firmly enough to the platen to spray ink onto the top 3 mm or so.

Comment: So how can I duplicate the printing behavior used by the windows photo viewer to print the image onto the full page